# How to rank rows based on two columns using SQLite

Tags: sqlite, count, sql-update, common-table-expression, window-functions

I have a table like this. I want to rank each row based on the date column so that the end result is the same rank if the two values of record_number and date are equal and different rank if the record_number and date is different. For example, the first two rows in the following table should have rank 1, while the third row should take rank 2 since the date is different but the record_number is the same.

| record number | date |
| --- | --- |
| 4648 | 2015-06-17 |
| 4648 | 2015-06-17 |
| 4648 | 2015-06-18 |
| 4897 | 2015-12-03 |
| 6523 | 2020-01-09 |
| 6523 | 2022-04-01 |

I used this logic but all rows ranked as 1.

```
ALTER TABLE main_clinics
    ADD COLUMN visit_rank INTEGER;
UPDATE main_clinics
    SET
    visit_rank = (
        SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY record_number ORDER BY date ASC)
        FROM main_clinics 
    );
```

Comment: What about the other rows? What is your expected output for this sample data?

Comment: @forpas if the row is completely duplicated the rank should be the same. If two rows have the same record number but different date, the rank should be consecutive: 1 for the older date and 2 for the newest date

Comment: My question is what rank do you expect for rows 4, 5 and 6

Comment: 1, 1, 2 repectively

Comment: `SET` expects a single value. When using a subquery that returns multiple rows, the first one is used and the rest discarded. See https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#subquery_expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your version of SQLite is 3.33.0+ you can use a cte that returns all the ranks and with the [`UPDATE...FROM`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_) syntax join it to the table:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY record_number ORDER BY date) AS rnk
  FROM main_clinics
)
UPDATE main_clinics AS m
SET visit_rank = c.rnk 
FROM cte AS c
WHERE c.record_number = m.record_number AND c.date = m.date;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/rtwKyrEx).

For older versions of SQLite use a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE main_clinics AS m1
SET visit_rank = (
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT date)
  FROM main_clinics AS m2
  WHERE m2.record_number = m1.record_number AND m2.date <= m1.date
);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/RnPRb336).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need either `RANK` or `DENSE_RANK`:

```sql
UPDATE main_clinics AS mc
SET visit_rank = (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT record_number, date FROM main_clinics) AS d
    WHERE d.record_number = mc.record_number
        AND d.date <= mc.date
);
```

Or, if you insist on using it, use `UPDATE FROM` (3.33.0+):

```sql
UPDATE main_clinics
SET visit_rank = mc2.r
FROM (
    SELECT record_number, date,
            DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY record_number ORDER BY date) AS r
    FROM main_clinics
) AS mc2 
WHERE main_clinics.date = mc2.date 
    AND main_clinics.record_number = mc2.record_number;
```